# Extra Space After Image in DIV Element

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML document, it contains a div and a img element. There is an extra space after img element.

Snippet is in below.

I tried it in Chrome and Firefox.

How can remove extra space after image element? I want to make div element height same with image.

Thanks.

```html
<div style="background-color:green">
    <img src="https://cdn.cvmer.com/rapor/bg/E5402F.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: add css 

img {
  display: block;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `img` a block element.

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:green">
  <img src="https://cdn.cvmer.com/rapor/bg/E5402F.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Strange behaviour. When I write all HTML in one line, extra space remains. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: From what I know, inline elements have this problem, but I think the next line problem is mostly for those that have extra space in-between elements. I'll remove the second sentence

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add this CSS

```
img {
  display: block;
}
<div style="background-color:green">
    <img src="https://cdn.cvmer.com/rapor/bg/E5402F.png" />
</div>
```